# Using Typescript, how do I type the functional True function?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, eslint, typescript-eslint, typed-lambda-calculus

For background, I am going through the "Flock of Functions" and doing my best to convert these Javascript examples to typed Typescript. See https://github.com/glebec/lambda-talk/blob/master/src/index.js#L152 for reference. The True function returns the first curried argument, and ignores the second.

Consider the following Typescript code:

```
interface ElsFn<T> {
  (els: unknown): T;
}

interface True extends Function {
  <T>(thn: T): ElsFn<T>;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
const T: True = (thn) => (_els) => thn;

console.log(T('true')('false'));
```

Assuming I want to keep the "explicit-function-return-type" rule, how do I get rid of the ESLint disable comment? In other words, I want to properly type the True function.

My editor tells me the problem is with the `(_els) => thn` portion of the code. It needs to be typeed somehow.

[image]
]

What can I do to set the return type or otherwise get this thing properly typed so that I don't need to disable the ESLint rule?

Comment: You defined your `True` type as generic. Then you should give your parameter a type to make your function have a return type : `(thn: AType) => (_els) => thn;` Else it will have any type.

Comment: Can you please explain a little farther? I'm pretty sure the way I have it the generic type flows to the final return value. The problem is the eslint rule doesn't seem to understand it. For example, if I pass a string as the first argument, it knows the return value is a string.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to specify generic arguments and return types:

```js
const T: True = <T_>(thn) => <T_>(_els):T_ => thn;
```

Comment: Thanks! That got me really close! The solution I settled on was: `const T = <T_>(thn: T_) => (_els: unknown): T_ => thn;`

Answer (score 0):

```
(_els): boolean => thn;
```

Could it be working for your case?

Comment: I don't think so because in the functional True function, the arguments can be any type, not just booleans. I really recommend this amazing talk called "A Flock of Functions" which got me super intrigued. https://github.com/glebec/lambda-talk